# City water connection - can they make a connection at a hose bib?

Tags: water, pipe, installation, water-pressure, utilities

I'm converting from well system to city water. My well pump and water inlet are in the back. I have a hose bib on the front of the house which would save money using less pipe/digging. So couldn't they just make connection at the hose bib? Or, is it typical to make connection at the current house water inlet location, which would be by the pump in this case all the way in the back? My basic understanding is that they could technically tap in anywhere in the cold water line and it will pressurize the whole house, both hot and cold. Is that accurate or am I missing something? I would like to know before giving instructions to the city utility crew.

Comment: If you mean to say that you propose to make the connection directly to the cold water piping *at the hose bib location*, rather than a connection *directly to the hose bib*, please edit your question to indicate that because those are two very different proposals. Nobody would recommend a direct tie-in to a hose bib outlet (I hope).

Comment: Might want a prv too, just in case

Answer (score 3):

I doubt seriously that the city crew would connect your water supply to a hose bib no matter what you told them. It is just too far outside of the norm.  For one thing, If you live in a climate that experiences sub-freezing temperatures in the winter your pipes would freeze and burst.  Virtually no one does it this way.  you want a good deep ditch between the house and the water supply to lay the pipe in, below the frost line.  Enter the house through the foundation wall below the frost line and connect to the cold water line at a good and convenient location.  In the years to come, you will be glad you did. (In an emergency and for a short period of time, yes you could connect to the hose bib.  It would work.)

Comment: Also the new connection must be made to the existing cold water system in a place where the largest diameter pipe that exists in the house.  For example in my house, the cold water distribution system consists of 1”, 3/4” and 1/2” pipe... tapping the new water supply in somewhere 1/2” or 3/4” parts of the system would not make sense as it would restrict flow.